# Column 'wine_id' in field list is ambiguous Error and cant work out why

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried researching on google and on here, but it really isn't making sense to me. Keep getting the error below. Any examples or updates will be great.

```
$this->db->select("wineinfo.*, wine_id, Vintage, Region,id,");
$this->db->from("wineinfo");
$this->db->where(["wine_id" => "19"]);
$this->db->join("wines", "wineinfo.wine_id = wines.id");
$wine = $this->db->get()->row();
```

Error Number: 1052

Column 'wine_id' in field list is ambiguous

SELECT `wineinfo`.*, `wine_id`, `Vintage`, `Region`, `id` FROM (`wineinfo`) JOIN `wines` ON `wineinfo`.`wine_id` = `wines`.`id` WHERE `wine_id` = '19'

Filename: /home/winebay/public_html/views/single-listing.php

Line Number: 20

Comment: Probably doesn't know if you are referring to wine_id in table wineinfo or table wines.

Comment: You have `wine_id` in both tables (wineinfo and wines). Being not ambiguous means you explicitly specify which table's column is to be selected (even if they have the same values). You can do that by preceding the column name with either table name or an alias in the select list: `\`wineinfo\`.\`wine_id\``

Comment: @marekful But look at the join condition.  The join column in `wines` is `id`, not `wine_id`.  So there may be a design problem here on top of the problem in the OP.

Comment: that id was meant to say wine_id. Error when I copied and pasted, as i was trying to see what happens if i changed it to id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `wine_id` from the explicit select list:

```
$this->db->select("wineinfo.*, Vintage, Region, id");
$this->db->from("wineinfo");
$this->db->where(["wineinfo.wine_id" => "19"]);
$this->db->join("wines", "wineinfo.wine_id = wines.wine_id");
$wine = $this->db->get()->row();
```

This error usually happens because MySQL can't figure out from *which* table the `wine_id` column is coming.  By removing `wine_id` from the select list, you are only selecting `wineinfo.wine_id`, which is not ambiguous.

Comment: Tried that and it gives me Column 'wine_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: @JohnMartyn Use `WHERE wineinfo.wine_id = 19`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Appreciate the help and advice. Merry christmas!